# I have a problem inserting my listview items in ,msaccess in VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have a problem inserting my listview items in vb.net AND it states INSERT into statement is wrong.. How can i go about this error and what are quick and easy fix?

```
 For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items

  Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ADMIN\source\repos\TrooTeaFinal\Database\Loginform.accdb")
  Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT into Order([Customer Name], [Address], [Phone], [Drink], [Quantity], [Size], [Size Price], [Add Ons], [Total of Add Ons], [Discount], [Payment], [DeliveryFee], [AmountPayable], [Date Of Order] VALUES (@Customer Name,@Address,@Phone,@Drink,@Quantity@,@Size,@Size Price,@Add Ons,@Total of Add Ons,@Discount,@Payment,@DeliveryFee,@AmountPayable,@Date Of Order)", conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Customer Name", item.SubItems(0).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", item.SubItems(1).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", item.SubItems(2).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Drink", item.SubItems(3).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", item.SubItems(4).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", item.SubItems(5).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size Price", item.SubItems(6).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Add Ons", item.SubItems(7).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total of Add Ons", item.SubItems(8).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", item.SubItems(9).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment", item.SubItems(10).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryFee", item.SubItems(11).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmountPayable", item.SubItems(12).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date Of Order", item.SubItems(13).Text)

    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()

  Next  

  MessageBox.Show("Payment Successful!")
```

Comment: If you declare a variable in VB, would you expect to be able to put spaces in it? Why would you think that would be OK in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy fix would be remove the space, so it would be

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items

  Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ADMIN\source\repos\TrooTeaFinal\Database\Loginform.accdb")
  Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Order] ([Customer Name], [Address], [Phone], [Drink], [Quantity], [Size], [Size Price], [Add Ons], [Total of Add Ons], [Discount], [Payment], [DeliveryFee], [AmountPayable], [Date Of Order]) VALUES (@CustomerName, @Address, @Phone, @Drink, @Quantity, @Size, @SizePrice, @AddOns, @TotalOfAddOns, @Discount, @Payment, @DeliveryFee, @AmountPayable, @DateOfOrder)", conn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", item.SubItems(0).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", item.SubItems(1).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", item.SubItems(2).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Drink", item.SubItems(3).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", item.SubItems(4).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", item.SubItems(5).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SizePrice", item.SubItems(6).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddOns", item.SubItems(7).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalOfAddOns", item.SubItems(8).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", item.SubItems(9).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment", item.SubItems(10).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryFee", item.SubItems(11).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmountPayable", item.SubItems(12).Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfOrder", item.SubItems(13).Text)

    conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()

Next  

  MessageBox.Show("Payment Successful!")
```

Comment: its still syntax error

Comment: mind to tell what is the error? Btw, your code missing a `)` just before VALUES and an extra `@` after `@Quantity`. Might want to check that!

Comment: As well as the obvious issue with spaces, `ORDER` is a reserved word, as in `ORDER BY` so the table name must be escaped with brackets. I have edited the answer.

Comment: this code of yours states data mismatch on critical expression

Comment: That means you need to convert the value to insert based on your access data type. Like for example your `Quantity` might be an Integer, so you need to convert `item.SubItems(4).Text` to an Integer